# Select rows with same values in relationship Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models in my project

`Product` and `Product attributes`
The relationship between them is one to many, so i can get product with relative attributes. Now I need to get a list of products and also get common product attributes between selected products. As in ex:

**Product**

| id | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Pear |
| 3 | Ananas |

**Product attributes**

| id | attribute | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fruit | 1 |
| 2 | fruit | 2 |
| 3 | fruit | 3 |
| 4 | green | 1 |
| 5 | yellow | 2 |
| 6 | brown | 3 |

Now when I'm extracting all 3 products, i want to get their common attributes, in this case the common attribute is "fruit". How can I do this with laravel eloquent?

Comment: Ok. And then? How can I get only common attributes?

Comment: @N69S `whereIn` is not good here, because it will return the result with one coincidence and we need all

Comment: really? let's go check, this query return attribute if it has the product  with id 1 OR id 2 OR id 3, but we need AND here

Comment: I want to get attributes only if they have the same content, as in example.

Answer (score 0):

As per your current schema (which doesn't look good) you can get common attributes as

```
$products = Product::take(3)->get();
```

From above products collect product ids

```
$productIds = $products->pluck('id');
```

And then query `product_attributes` matching previously collected `$productIds`, this query will involve aggregation to satisfy your condition for common attributes.

```
$attributes = DB::table('product_attributes')
                ->select(['name',DB::raw('count(distinct product_id) total_count')])
                ->whereIn('product_id', $productIds)
                ->groupBy('name')
                ->havingRaw('total_count = ?', [count($productIds)])
                ->get();
```

Above query will return common attributes by checking the result of `count()` expression with count of `$productIds` if they match and this means that every products has this attributed attached to it.